# How to make a POST request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postman

I created an API. Get request works. I try to perform POST request.

In `HomeController`

```php
<?php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = Auth::user()->name;
        $ip = Request::ip();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'ip' => $request->input('ip')
        ]);
        return $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

My routes

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/api/person', 'HomeController@store');
```

I try to Post through POSTMAN.

Got "message":

> "CSRF token mismatch.", "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"...

Where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the route from CSRF protection in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/api/person'
    ];
}
```

This is ideal for testing using Postman but you should post a valid `X-CSRF-TOKEN` when performing API calls from Javascript

And in your controller you have several issues

```php
<?php

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // REMOVE THIS
        // $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // UNUSED VARIABLES, REMOVE THEM
        // $name = Auth::user()->name;
        // $ip = Request::ip();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'ip' => $request->input('ip')
        ]);
        return $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Got "message": "Unauthenticated."

Comment: remove `$this->middleware('auth');` from HomeController's constructor method

Comment: The same result.

Comment: Uhh I can't keep guessing, edit your question and include all of the routes and post your entire controller

Comment: You didn't remove the auth middleware from HomeController ._.

Comment: I did. I posted my code, but I tried to comment out this line and also get rid of Auth::check. But result is the same -"message": "Unauthenticated."

Comment: `Auth::user` is using the web guard, use the api guard for such authentication instead

Comment: And that's totally a different question, my answer solves the error you posted on your question

Comment: And you're not using the variables at all, I'll update my answer with a correct controller

Comment: It would help me to make a successful POST request?

Comment: Updated my answer, and yes

Comment: No, but if you want to use /api routes and protect them behind auth middleware, then you have a lot to do, [read this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)